# Display breadcrumbs of pages in a website

Tags: struts2, struts, breadcrumbs

I am very new to struts2 I want know how can I display navigation of pages in a website like

home->login->your account->xx-> etc in the current JSP page

Comment: it dependents upon what type of breadcrumbs you want?

Comment: There is an old plugin: https://cwiki.apache.org/S2PLUGINS/breadcrumbs-plugin.html, but you better of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it like this

```
<div id="nav"> <s:a action="actionName_resultName" id="nav">Retailers </s:a> - Coupon      Options</div>
```